# Spring Integration get FTP files recursively with outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I'm trying to get all files within a directory structure of 3 levels deep.
For example:
- the image a.jpg exists in a folder /images/12/34/
- the image b.jpg exists in a folder /images/56/78

I've tried the outbound-gateway like stated in :

> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/ftp/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/FtpOutboundGatewaySample-context.xml 
> and 
>     http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/104612-inbound-ftp-polling-sub-directories?p=604430#post604430

My configuration :

```
<bean id="ftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="port" value="21"/>
    <property name="username" value="Administrator"/>
    <property name="password" value="SgtSpeedy1"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="2" />
</bean>

<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
    cache-sessions="false"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inbound"
    command="ls"
    command-options=""
    expression="'/images/*/*'"
    reply-channel="toSplitter"/>

<int:channel id="toSplitter" />
<int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter channel="toSplitter" append-newline="true"/>
```

I've omitted the splitter and just print everything out for testing purposes.

When testing, I do not get any file.
I've tried setting the folder to /images/* and then it returns all images under the 'images' folder but not recursively as stated in the links provided. So folders /12/34 and /56/78 aren't taken into account.

I cannot see what I'm missing. Can anyone help?

P.S. I'm working on Spring Integration 2.2.6 without the option to upgrade to 4.0.2 (newest), because I'm using a framework. Otherwise I'd use the -R option for the gateway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested with `foo/foo/bar/qux.txt` and `foo/foo/baz/fiz.txt` with

```
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayLS"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inbound"
    command="ls"
    command-options="-1"
    expression="'foo/*/*'"
    reply-channel="toSplitter"/>
```

and it worked fine; as expected...

`11:34:55.983 DEBUG [main] ...[Payload ArrayList content=[fiz.txt, qux.txt]]...`

(I added the -1 option to just get the filename).

This was using linux ftpd on the server side.

Are you sure the files are in `/images` and not `images`? (Or is the user chrooted so `/` is his home)?

Comment: Gary, thanks for your reply. Files are in /images but had tested 'images' also. That didn't work.   

Created the foo structure as you described and got the same result...

When I leave the /*/* part after the 'images' folder, I do get the file information, but only for the top level (images) folder.   

/* gives the same result, and /*/* does not give any information at all, just an empty list.

Comment: Perhaps a permissions problem? Have you tried `ls /images/*/*` using a command line ftp client?

Comment: I get the error message : not understood. So I guess it should be an FTP issue then?

Comment: Yes; sounds like it (server problem).